# update command is denied for user

Tags: mysql, shared-hosting

I've been using [this](http://freehosting.com) free hosting site for development and testing.

I couldn't use an `UPDATE` MySQL command to change the database values, even though the user is supposed to be allowed to use all commands from cPanel.

Then, I've tested the same with a default user, it still won't work. However, it works fine on my system.

The MySQL error is

`UPDATE command denied to user 'test'@'localhost' for table 'content'`

Other commands are working fine.

Why is this happening? And how can it be prevented? Or any solution for this?

And I am very sure that users have permission to use the `UPDATE` command because I can use phpMyAdmin with the same user and modify the MySQL fields.

I don't understand why some MySQL commands from PHP are denied for a user who was given all priviliges and can do everything via phpMyAdmin. Given that script, phpMyAdmin and the SQL host are on the same server.

Comment: why is this question voted down?

Comment: well. the question is what is the solution or fix for this. updated

Comment: I think the error is self-explanatory - wherever you're running this command, `test@localhost` does not have UPDATE permissions on that table. The solution would be to GRANT permissions - or check with your free host that it is even permitted.

Comment: I have already mentioned that I've added the permissions through cpanel

Comment: @Widor: This is valid question, just do not use mouse the way you want, use some brain.. No need to vote down straight away, if you do not have time to answer small question leave it to others , you might have good knowledge, give some respect to fellow members. Hope you remember you are of same level when you started your career.

Comment: @StewieFG My point (which if you check the [Edit History](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7980032/revisions)) applied at the time, was that he OP had not actually asked a question.

Comment: I had a screwy error similar to this a while back. Have you been running update/insert queries on your `mysql`.`users` table by any chance? I did this once, and the only way I could get it to actually grant the permissions it said it was granting was to reinstall MySQL

Comment: just to check something : are you able to do an `INSERT`?

Comment: yes, I can, only the update is not working

Comment: Yea, sounds similar to the problem I had. Would reinstalling be an option? It fixed this problem for me.

Comment: Bt I cannot re-install mysql on shared server

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For everyone who have tried answering this question here is my sincere thanks.  I have found the problem and solution.

my sql query is like this

```
UPDATE `dblayer`.`test` SET `title` = 'hello a' WHERE `test`.`id` =1;
```

which I got from phpmyadmin and it works perfectly on my system.
But when I work on the servers it doesn't work and it says command denied may be because

```
`dblayer`.`test`
```

I am trying to select the table globally (or something like that, I'm not sure)
but if my sql query is

```
UPDATE `test` SET `title` = 'hello a' WHERE `test`.`id` =1;
```

it works on my server too.

Comment: That _really _seems like a bug.  But at least there's a work-around.

Comment: Had the exact same problem. Seems really counter intuitive.

Answer (score 8):

As everyone else said, it's permission issue. I am sure you probably checked, but just in case. After you log into phpmyadmin, run the following:

```
SELECT USER();
```

That should spit out 'test'@'localhost' as indicated in all the comments above

Then run

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR  'test'@'localhost'
```

That should give you all privs for that user. When you get results, select 'Options', Full Text and click go  to get full text.

Make sure permissions in the output have something like that:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `your_database`.* TO 'test'@'localhost'
```

You might not be able to get GRANT ALL on some hosting setups but as long as you got INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE  you should definitely be able to update the data

Comment: Could you paste your whole GRANT ALL result. Is it GRANT ALL on `your_database`.* TO 'test'@'localhost'? or GRANT ALL on some tables only. Another (possibly obvious) step would be to contact your hosting vendor. If you have all the permissions set and can't update the table, they should be able to help you

Comment: Worked on windows phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 6):

Your user doesn't have the right permissions. You need to give it access to the UPDATE command, like so:

```
GRANT UPDATE ON database.* TO test@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

If you are using a graphical tool to manage the database - e.g. PHPMyAdmin or SQLYog, etc - you should be able to use those tools to enable these permissions too.

Comment: user does have permissions. because I can modify the content through phpmyadmin.

Comment: But rather then GRANT SELECT it should be GRANT UPDATE, or if you want to give the user full permission: GRANT ALL

Comment: and when you log in through phpmyadmin do you use the same username/password as user `test`? Very likely this is not the case.

Comment: @Oldskool: oops ;) Corrected.

Comment: @pahnin try GRANT UPDATE ON database.* TO test@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, the permission was right but it was working in some environments and not in others.  I was using a table name like

**scheme.TABLE_NAME**.

Without changing the permission but using just

**table_name**

worked in all environments.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is a case sensitive problem.

MySQL also says access denied even if the table is not available. Please make sure that you have no case sensitive issues.

Comment: I had this problem with an sql file (an application db structure upgrade file).  I had granted an application account user full access to the app's database, but kept getting permission denied.  After pulling out half of my hair, I finally noticed that some knob had hard-coded the table name into one command in the middle of this huge file.  The table name was the name of the app, not the name of the table, so it didn't stick out to me. :/

Comment: that did it for me >.<

Comment: "MySQL also says access denied even if the table is not available" - this was my issue too.  The permissions looked correct but the UPDATE statement had a typo in the DB name and so it was giving a permission error instead of saying the db/table was not found.

Answer (score 2):

> the my sql error is UPDATE command denied to user 'test'@'localhost'
>   for table 'content'
>
> why is this happening? And how to prevent it? Or any solution for
>   this?

It's happening for what it says it's happening: the user `test` does not have update permissions on table `content`. Something like this should grant the user the required permission:

```
GRANT UPDATE ON database.content TO test@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

*password above is just a place holder. You should use the real one.

Comment: @pahnin you didn't specify whether your app connects locally to the server or remotely. Note that the user may have permissions to UPDATE only from localhost. If you are connecting remotely, it needs to be granted specifically in the way `GRANT UPDATE ... to  test@your.ip.address ...`

Answer (score 2):

A `UPDATE command denied` error can on some web hosts be the result of reaching the MySQL database space limit.

Comment: I had exactly this issue. On ClearDb for Azure

Comment: Exactly the same, was driving me insane inside Sequel Pro on a ClearDB instance on Heroku, even had to roll back databases changes... urgh. Winner of a comment. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full access to test user with ip as localhost.Check the user table from mysql db.

Login as root and enter into mysql database and then to user table.You will be finding the current privileges of your test user.

Answer (score 0):

This error came up for me when I was creating triggers, which included an update clause, for remote MySql instance (via JawsDB).

#### Instead of setting up trigger this:

``` CREATE TRIGGER updateRecentDateFromProcGen 
After Insert On ``mq6swfzd39ygjejl``.``proceduregeneration`` 
For Each Row
BEGIN
    UPDATE ``mq6swfzd39ygjejl``.``users``
    SET 
        mostRecentDateAllActivities = NEW.date
    WHERE
        NEW.userID = users.ID;
END ```

#### I set it up like this

``` CREATE TRIGGER updateRecentDateFromProcGen 
After Insert On ``mq6swfzd39ygjejl``.``proceduregeneration`` 
For Each Row
BEGIN
    UPDATE ``users``
    SET 
        mostRecentDateAllActivities = NEW.date
    WHERE
        NEW.userID = users.ID;
END ```
Basically, I just removed the database name in the UPDATE line and left the table name by itself.

#### Note, wherever you see the `` there should only be one tilde  not two. If anyone knows how to fix that in stack overflow's markup please let me know!

Answer (score -1):

With mysql you can just do 
     SELECT * mysql.user

Look at the privileges and then update the ones you want. I like that more personally then using the above commands because I can see all of my options available in that table.

```
 UPDATE  mysql.user 
 SET  Insert_priv =  'Y',
 Update_priv =  'Y' 
 WHERE  user.Host =  'localhost' AND  user.User =  'test';
```

After updating the privileges I noticed I would have to restart the mysql server for the client to see them:

```
 /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Then it would work fine