# stored procedure won't work on different databases with correct privileges

Tags: mysql

show grant result

```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON A.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON B.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
```

I use the stored procedure to select some rows from B.tableB and try to update A.tableA but I get `UPDATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'tableA'` when I execute the procedure.
if I use A and update tableA in the terminal it will work.This is similar to
[update command is denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980032/update-command-is-denied-for-user.But) he also doesn't know why this happens and I cannot change database in stored procedure.

Comment: Flush privileges?  Select * from mysql.user (for that user and host) ?

Comment: my account is not a real root account, it has proper privileges for all the databases related to my website.

Comment: it turns out that I have a typo in the database  name